# Gauss Law Doubt

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I have a doubt regarding whether or not I can take a spherical surface as a Gaussian surface when the taken Gaussian surface completely overlaps a symmetrical spherical charge distribution of same radius.
Won't it violate the fact that a Gaussian surface can not have charges on it.
Or would be okay for a continuous distribution.
Finally when we say continuous do we we mean continuous on the surface or do we mean continuous into the surface and out of the surface.

[image]

Comment: If the charges in the system are point charges, then you don't want to draw the circle to intersect a point charge.  If the charge is distributed continuously (an approximation!) then it's ok.

Comment: But what does continous actually mean ? Does it refer to charge being continuous over the surface irrespective of the fact whether a charge distribution exist above or below it.

Comment: A Gaussian surface can pass through a continuous charge distribution. A continuous charge distribution means that the charge isn't confined to any particular point in space. It's distributed over space. When we are asked to find the force between two charges by using Coulomb's law, the underlying assumption is that the charges are point charges. On the other hand, a Gaussian surface **cannot** pass through a discrete (_point_) charge. The field tends to blow up around a point charge as you get really really close to it. That's why we don't make a Gaussian surface pass through a point charge.

Comment: See it for yourself. As the distance $r$ from the _point_ charge tends to $0$. The force or field tends to $∞$. And things get weird.

Comment: "_I'm starting to doubt that cows are actually spherical..._"

Comment: @KunalPawar The last question that remains in my mind is that would this distribution be counted in the charge enclosed?

Comment: aim of the gauss is to help in the calculation of field using coulombs where the symmetry includes all those points which have an identical magnitude of the field so you choose such a gaussian surface which includes all the possible charges to find a field at the particular point.so if you cross you gaussian surface then the field will be zero, now if you consider a system of charges as you mentioned there should be some thickness to get some value and it would be rigrous integral!

Answer (score -1):

Gaussian surface is an imaginary plane which we draw so that we would know how much of electric field lines are passing through that imaginary area we took(flux).Hence it will give perfectly correct answer. This can sbe proved by using Coulombs  law and Gaussian law for the same surface 
[image]
And the charge "+q" is already distributed on the surface in the figure
1)Applying coulombs law $$\sigma=q\left(4\pi r^2\right)$$=The charge density by area.
By coulombs law ,$$E=-\frac{dV}{dr}$$Hence total potential at the center 
is $$\frac{K\sigma\left(4\pi r^2\right)}{r}$$
$$E=-\frac{d\left(\frac{K\sigma\left(4\pi r^2\right)}{r}\right)}{dr}$$
$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0}}$$
2) by Gauss law 
$$\oint E dS=\phi$$
Now according to gauss law$\phi$ for any closed symmetric surface is $$\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$$ 
So And distribution of the charge is  on the surface so
$$E4\pi r^2=\frac{q}{\epsilon_{0}}$$
$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0}}$$
Hence proved Gauss law is correct for this case also

Comment: A mathematical theorem (i.e. Gauss' Law) cannot be proved by an example.